# How can I get a VLAX-OBJECT from an ads_name type

Tags: lisp, autolisp

I am using entget function in order to get all the properties of a certain object. So I have the table of dotted pairs that describe the properties of the object but now I want to use the VLAX-OBJECT functions, such as VLAX-COPY or VLAX-MOVE. So I need to convert it from the ads_name type to VLAX-OBJECT type but I can not handle to do it. Can you suggest any Idea to do it please?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [vlax-ename->vla-object](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/AutoCAD-AutoLISP/files/GUID-BD451263-76D5-4A93-B50A-3C27E89A0AD4-htm.html) function to get the VLAX object from the entity name